# Batch or VBscript to run to sequential processes conditionally

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder (ENTEC) on Computer A where data gets downloaded daily. This data gets copied to another computer (B) where a schedule runs an FTP upload for processing. I need help with script or batch that:

1. Copies the content of the folder (ENTEC) from Computer A to a shared folder on another computer's shared folder (Computer B).
2. If the previous step is successful then Copy the same folder from Computer A (ENTEC) to a shared folder on our file server for backup purposes. Copy only new files not existing ones
3. After successful copy to backup then delete the contents of ENTEC on Computer A.

I can manage the FTP side and its schedule so I don't need help with the FTP side only VBS or BAT.

Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little batch will do it, if I've understood the problem correctly.

```
robocopy \\computerA\path\to\ENTEC \\computerB\path\to\sharedFolder /e /mir ^
&& robocopy \\computeA\path\to\ENTEC \\computerC\backup /e ^
&& rd /s \\computerA\path\to\ENTEC
```

A few notes:

- The && makes sure that the next command is only run if the one before it succeeded (by checking exit codes). &, on the other hand, would run the commands in sequence without checking for success or failure before running the next command.
- Note the use of the line continuation character, `^`. This really is one long chain of commands.
- This doesn't handle ENTEC changing during a run.
- This deletes the whole ENTEC directory in computerA. If you need it back, add a `&& mkdir \\computeA\path\to\ENTEC` at the end.
- The copy to the backup location will update any changed files. If you don't want to update them, add `/xc`.
- The `/mir` option in the first `robocopy` will delete anything in \\computerB\path\to\sharedFolder not in \\computerA\path\to\ENTEC. If you want the same behavior as the backup location, remove `/mir`

I'd also look at the output of `robocopy /?`. It can do a lot of stuff.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. The only issue I have with this great response is that I wanted it to be conditional meaning that the "RD" command should only execute if the above completes successfully, otherwise if something goes wrong and the backup did not occur I would delete the data in ENTEC.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated that answer explaining the difference between && and &. The use of && here was intentional to get the only delete if successful behavior.

Comment: Thanks again for remaining polite and professional. I know little about programming/scripting and your work really is incredible.